# Ordering across multiple table Only using AND in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a script that i have inherited that generates SQL on the fly and then executes it against a mySQL database.

Currently it is limited in its "WHERE" clause to simple WHERE AND AND AND statements

For example

```
SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'Volvo' AND Dealership = 'United' AND color ='White'
```

In the worst case it can string along 40 of these AND clauses

It is extremely simple for me to string on additional AND arguments.  It would be a pain in the butt to have to rewrite it.

My problem is this:  I need to search on a related table.  I need to figure out a way to maintain the AND AND AND,  but I can use as complex an argument in the AND as i would like.

So my code could look like

`SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'Volvo' AND (anything mySQL likes)  AND color ='White'`

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Trucks` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Make` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Current_PartList_ID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '1');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '2');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Mac', '3');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Mac', '5');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Daihatsu', '8');
INSERT INTO `Trucks` (`Make`, `Current_PartList_ID`) VALUES ('Volvo', '4');


CREATE  TABLE `Parts_lists` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Carb_Model` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Carb_date` DATE NULL ,
  `Tire_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Tire_date` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Hirsch', '2012-12-19', 'Toyo', '2013-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('HIrsch', '2013-02-14', 'Goodyear', '2011-03-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2011-11-04', 'Toyo', '2013-01-01');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Miller', '2009-10-11', 'Toyo', '2010-04-17');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2011-01-07', 'Goodyear', '2013-01-06');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Bosch', '2012-09-16', 'Lamb', '2012-06-25');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Miller', '2011-07-22', 'Unknown', '2012-04-07');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Davis', '2009-03-09', 'Hawking', '2012-06-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Sanno', '2010-01-07', 'Goodyear', '2009-07-16');
INSERT INTO `Parts_lists` (`Carb_Model`, `Carb_date`, `Tire_type`, `Tire_date`) VALUES ('Thrust', '2012-11-11', 'Lamb', '2004-04-08');
```

Keeping this AND structure in mind.  How would I get: All Volvo Trucks with Hirsch Carbs?

(In this case is records 1 and 2 in the Trucks table)

Comment: Maybe subqueries could help? Let a subquery return `1` for true or `0` for false.

Comment: Also, obligatory comment to not use `*` in selects... blah blah...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE Make = 'Volvo' AND Current_PartList_ID in (select ID from    Parts_List where Carb_Model = 'Hirsch')
```